# Splitting a string into key & value pair

Tags: java

I am spliting string with '&' . For Example:

```
password=XXXXXXXXX&username=XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Now if suppose my password contains '&' then i am facing issue here that the password gets trimed on first occurence of '&'.

Example:

```
password=disney&123&username=XXXXXXXXXXX
```

So my output will be as follows:

```
password=disney 
123 
username=XXXXXXXXXXX
```

But I want my output as:

```
password=disney&123 
username=XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Please guide me as i am new to java.
And i want to split the string using '&' only and my password may conatin '&' it depends on users.

Thanks in Advance,
Ritesh

Comment: `indexOf ("&username");`

Comment: you should read those separately...

Comment: You need to encode or escape special characters. See [URL Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding).

Comment: Is this a web application?

Comment: If you can control the source where the string comes from, you should encode the password before sending it.

Comment: you could use a positive lookahead as of `&(?=username)` when doing a `String#split`

Comment: This is for mobile application scary Wombat.

Comment: And why are you using part of the URL format in a mobile application ?

Comment: few things i would like to add is that there is a front end mobile application from where request comes and goes to downstream systems from where the required data is fetched.

Comment: Now this request goes to downstream system through a middle ware tool where in logic is there to split the string into key value pairs.

Comment: Here the logic  implemented  is that the string is splitted into key value pairs using '&' as the character to split strings.But user can have '&' in his/her password in that case this logic fails. So can u please suggest some solution. I cannot change the logic of splitting at the same time i want to include '&' in password.

Answer (score 2):

A more simple solution would be to use the URL encoding completly. Here you are using only the separator system but you should also use the encoding.

So when you build the String, encode the values, this will replace some character, you can use the [complet solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters) or simply replace the `&` with the value of your choice (but I would not do that).

Then, when you have split the String contains only the `&` used to separate values, decode the values (to recreate the original values).

This would be exactly the same as sending a request to a WebService, since you use the same pattern, this would seems more logic.

- Encode the values
- Concat the values with `&`
- Send the String
- Split the String using `&`
- Decode the values

Comment: Thanks appreciate your suggestions and prompt response

Comment: @RiteshKhatri This is a more generic solution, if you don't know the name of the parameter you will receive.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] strs="password=disney&123&username=XXXXXXXXXXX".split("&username=");
strs[1]="username="+strs[1];
System.out.println(strs[0]);
System.out.println(strs[1]);
```

--

Edit:

```
//This is a slightly more generalized method
String[] strs="username=XXXXXXXXXXX&password=disney&123".split("&(?=(username|password)=)");
System.out.println(strs[0]);
System.out.println(strs[1]);
```

--

Edit:

```
//more generalized method
String[] strs="username=XXXXXXXXXXX&password=disney&123".split("&(?=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)=)");
for(String str : strs)
    System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: But then what if the string it receives is formatted as "username=XXX$password=YYY"? From what OP is suggesting, it sounds like it should also be a parseable value.

Comment: @MikaelF OP's example is not url encoded (`password` contains unescaped literal `&`). For custom format, we need custom parser. Anyway I'll add a slightly more generalized method.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But this username and password is part of querystring in a url. The length i.e.. the number of parameters used to query may change  for example it can be:

Comment: saml=xxxxxxxxx&password=xxxxxxxxx&appVersion=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&username=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&token=xxxxxxxx

Comment: So i need a more generalized solution

Comment: @RiteshKhatri added.